# How to create an image using a matrix?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I want to know what color RGB[228, 198, 208] is, so I wrote this function:

```
function showColor()
im = ones(500, 500, 3);
color = ones(500, 500);
R = color * 228;
G = color * 198;
B = color * 208;
im(:, :, 1) = R;
im(:, :, 2) = G;
im(:, :, 3) = B;
imshow(im);
```

The result is white and it doesn't seem right.

Then I tried this:

```
function showColor2()
im = imread('pic.jpg'); %It's a 2448*3264 picture
color = ones(2448, 3264);
R = color * 228;
G = color * 198;
B = color * 208;
im(:, :, 1) = R;
im(:, :, 2) = G;
im(:, :, 3) = B;
imshow(im);
```

This function shows the right color but it looks just like the first one (except image size).

So my question is:

1. Is there any difference between the matrix we create and the one we get from `imread()`?

   Why the second function works well?
2. Can we create an image just by writing a matrix?

Comment: by default image/imshow displays floating point array as an image of range [0, 1]. If you want your image to be displayed as range of [0, 255] your need to pass the range into those functions. The second works because imread returns native data type, usually uint8, so your modified image stays as uint8 rather than double, then imshow displays uint8 array as a image of the range [0, 255] by default.

Comment: Your variable `colour` is unnecessary, you could also write `im(:, :, 1)=228;
im(:, :, 2)=198;
im(:, :, 3)=208;` (Not solving the problem, just simplifying your code or the code from the answer)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
im = ones(500, 500, 3,'uint8');
color = ones(500, 500,'uint8');
R = color * 228;
G = color * 198;
B = color * 208;
im(:, :, 1) = R;
im(:, :, 2) = G;
im(:, :, 3) = B;
imshow(im);
```

Matlab supports two different image formats. One is based on `double` arrays where the values are in the range 0 to 1.0 (This is the default type created by `ones`. Try typing `class(ones(500,500))`). The other is more efficient and is based on 8 bit per dimension. These arrays are created by `ones(N,M,'uint8')`.

To use the `double` image format use your original code but make sure the values are in the range 0 to 1.0. So, in your case:

```
im = ones(500, 500, 3);
color = ones(500, 500);
R = color * 228/256;
G = color * 198/256;
B = color * 208/256;
im(:, :, 1) = R;
im(:, :, 2) = G;
im(:, :, 3) = B;
imshow(im);
```